# Input method in C

Tags: c

How can I give an input from a text file, I mean when I execute it in the form:

```
./a.out input.txt
```

Comment: If you invoke the program like this `./a.out < input.txt`, then simply read from stdin.  Otherwise, `FILE *fp = fopen ("input.txt", "r");` to open the file, then read from it.

Answer (score 1):

In your C program, you receive `"input.txt"` as a string and open the file.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    /* Do stuff with file */

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

You will also have to add checks to see if the argument exists and if the file was opened properly. This example is just the basic concept.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the ./a.out < input.txt, your stdin gets input data form the file. For example `scanf()` will now get input data from the input.txt.

Answer (score 1):

C programs meant for execution from a command line typically take at least two parameters in their `main()` function: the number of arguments, and an array containing the arguments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

One of the first things you generally do is to interpret the arguments. In the example you provided, there are two: the name of the program itself, and the file name "input.txt". At that point, you can open "input.txt" and start reading, writing, or whatever.